# Harary's generalized Tic-Tac-Toe; Winning strategy for Skinny on a 7 x 7 board?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, game, tic-tac-toe

*Disclaimer:* The purpose of this post is a ask question, not to offer a puzzle. Still, there are some puzzles here for the reader's pleasure.

*Disclaimer 2:* This question was [also asked on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355825/how-to-find-winning-strategy-for-4-celled-animals-of-hararys-generalized-tic-ta/4357009#4357009). I gave an answer there which gives some partial progress.

---

Animal tic-tac-toe was conceived by Frank Harary in 1977. It is like regular tic-tac-toe, except it is played on a $b\times b$ board, for some integer $b$. Also, instead of trying to get three-in-a-row, both players are trying to make a certain polyomino shape with their marked squares. Any rotation or reflection of the polyomino counts as a win. The players are X and O, with X playing first. Each choice of $b$ and each choice of polyomino gives a different game. The five possible tetrominos were given the following cute names by Harary:

[image]

Using a strategy-stealing argument, you can prove that O cannot win under optimal play. Therefore, the question of interest is: for each polyomino, what is that smallest board size on which X can achieve that polyomino, and in how few moves can he do so?

The following data summarizes the known results for polyominos with three and four cells. I have seen these numbers published in several places, cited at the end. However, I cannot find a winning strategy for Skinny, the $4\times 1$ rectangle, on a 7 x 7 board.

> **Question:** Can X achieve a 4 x 1 rectangle on a 7 x 7 board? Remember that diagonals are not allowed. Can it be done in eight moves?

I understand that this is a hard question, and the answer would likely be a relatively complex strategy. I hope that it is actually answerable, since all of the sources below claimed it is true without proof, or the barest sketch of a proof.

> **Puzzles for the readers enjoyment:** Show how X can win for each of the other polyominos, on the given board sizes. Also, prove that X cannot achieve the 2x2 square on any board size.

| Polyomino | Minimal board size where X wins | Minimal number of moves for X to win |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Straight Tromino | 4 | 3 |
| Bent Tromino | 3 | 3 |
| Tippy (S Tetromino) | 3 | 5 |
| Elly (L Tetromino) | 4 | 4 |
| Knobby (T Tetromino) | 5 | 4 |
| Fatty (2x2 Square) | X cannot win on any board size | N/A |
| **Skinny** (4x1 rectangle) | **7?** | **8?** |

Sources that claim that Skinny is achievable on a 7 x 7 in 8 moves, all without proof:

> Beck, József (2008),  *Combinatorial Games: Tic-Tac-Toe Theory*, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 114, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, pp. 60–64, doi https://doi.org/10.1017%2FCBO9780511735202
>
> Gardner, M. (2001). *The colossal book of mathematics: Classic puzzles, paradoxes, and problems.* W. W. Norton.
>
> Harary, Frank, "Achieving the Skinny Animal," Eureka, No. 42, Summer 1982, pp.
> 8-14; Errata, No. 43, Easter, 1983, pp. 5-6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel Mathias has solved this question in a [comment on the MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355825/how-to-find-winning-strategy-for-4-celled-animals-of-hararys-generalized-tic-ta/4357009#comment9097163_4357009), so for completeness I will summarize the entire strategy here.

X starts by claiming the center. Up to symmetry, O's response is one of the nine squares below:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&&&&& \\\hline
&&&&&& \\\hline
&&&&&& \\\hline
&&&X_1&&& \\\hline
&&\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&\;\;\;\;&\;\;\;\;&\;\;\; \\\hline
&\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&&& \\\hline
\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&&& \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
I have winning strategies for seven of these responses, as shown below:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&&&&\color{gray}{O_3}& \\\hline
&&&X_4&\color{gray}{X_5}&X_3& \\\hline
&&&\color{gray}{X_5}&&\color{gray}{O_3}& \\\hline
&&\color{gray}{O_2}&X_1&\color{gray}{O_2}&X_2&\color{gray}{O_2} \\\hline
&&&&\;\;\;\;&\color{gray}{O_3}&\;\;\; \\\hline
&\color{gray}{O_1}&&\color{gray}{O_1}&&& \\\hline
\color{gray}{O_1}&\color{gray}{O_1}&&\color{gray}{O_1}&&& \\\hline
\end{array}\qquad 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&\color{gray}{O_3}&&&& \\\hline
&&\color{gray}{O_3}&\color{gray}{X_5}&&& \\\hline
&&X_3&X_4&\color{gray}{X_5}&& \\\hline
&\color{gray}{O_2}&X_2&X_1&\color{gray}{O_2}&& \\\hline
&&\color{gray}{O_3}&&&\;\;\;\;&\;\;\; \\\hline
&&\color{gray}{O_1}&&&& \\\hline
\;\;\;\;&&\color{gray}{O_1}&&&& \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

All that remains is when O responds either orthogonally or diagonally adjacent to the center. These lines of play were worked out by Daniel Mathias:

[image]